# What does "text" in JLS 3.1 Unicode refer to?

Tags: java, jls

Section [3.1 Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-3.html) of the JLS states:

> The Java programming language represents text in sequences of 16-bit code units, using the UTF-16 encoding.

What does "text" refer to?

I'm wondering if it refers to

- content stored in `String` objects?
- the source code as a whole which is passed to the compiler, meaning that this is an instruction for the compiler that the first thing it has to do is to convert the source code internally to UTF-16 before processing it further?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That particular sentence is referring to how text data is represented by Java programs; i.e. `String` and related types.

However, one needs to be careful about reading too much into this.

1. What it really means is that text data is *modeled* as a sequence of UTF-16 code points.  And it is really about how the JLS deals with those aspects of the Java *language* relate to text handling; i.e. how String literals are modeled.  The JLS itself doesn't specify the `String` API.  That is specified by the javadocs: a separate document.  In reality, the JLS only specifies (or implies) that strings have certain properties.
2. It is no longer literally correct that Java `String` objects are *represented* as UTF-16.  Since Java 9 the `String` class uses a hybrid representation for string values.  Strings are now *internally* represented using a `byte[]` rather than a `char[]`.  If a string consists solely of LATIN-1 code-points, it is encoded with one `byte` per code-unit.  If the string contains any code-units outside of the LATIN-1 range, it is encoded in UTF-16.

   In short, a `String` is *modeled* by the javadocs as *both* a sequence of UTF-16 code-units *and* a sequence of Unicode code-points.  The internal representation is more complicated.
3. A Java application can actually choose to model and represent text anyway it wants to; i.e. any way that makes sense for the application.  It doesn't have to use `String` or related classes.  (Obviously, if an application chooses not to use `String` and so on, some things are more complicated.  For example, Java's String literal syntax yields only `String` objects, and many other APIs require `String` values.)

If you take those caveats together, the particular sentence we are talking about is best viewed as explanatory rather than prescriptive.

---

The Java compiler represents (Java source code) text internally the same way as most other Java program do; i.e. using `String` and related types.  *However that is an implementation detail*.  So long as Unicode in Java source code is supported properly by the compiler, it doesn't matter how it is represented at compile time.

("Supported properly" means in accordance with whatever the JLS specifies.)